# How to add cors in my Graphql server(Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, axios

I am having a problem in applying cors in my graphql server because it doesnt work, ive researched a lot, still all of it does not work.

This is the code:

```js
import { BasicServer } from 'realm-object-server'
import * as path from 'path'
import { GraphQLService } from 'realm-graphql-service'`enter code here`
import {cors} from 'cors'

const server = new BasicServer()

server.addService(new GraphQLService({
    // Turn this off in production!
    disableAuthentication: true
}))

server.start({
        // This is the location where ROS will store its runtime data
        dataPath: path.join(__dirname, '../data'),
        middlewares: [cors()]

    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Realm Object Server was started on ${server.address}`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`Error starting Realm Object Server: ${err.message}`)
    })
```

How to successfully apply cors in this graphql server?

Comment: I think you are importing `cors` the wrong way, try this `import * as cors from 'cors'`

Comment: Thank you :D. i just realized this right after i posted this question hahhaa thanks though :D this would be helpful to everyone.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are importing cors the wrong way, try this:

```js
import { BasicServer } from 'realm-object-server'
import * as path from 'path'
import { GraphQLService } from 'realm-graphql-service'`enter code here`
import * as cors from 'cors' // <====

const server = new BasicServer()

server.addService(new GraphQLService({
    // Turn this off in production!
    disableAuthentication: true
}))

server.start({
        // This is the location where ROS will store its runtime data
        dataPath: path.join(__dirname, '../data'),
        middlewares: [cors()]

    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Realm Object Server was started on ${server.address}`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`Error starting Realm Object Server: ${err.message}`)
    })
```

Comment: If you import it as `import * as cors from 'cors'` then `cors` is an object not a function, so you cannot invoke it. Also check https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Check: http://brianflove.com/2017/03/22/express-cors-typescript/
and it seems that someone faced the same issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-object-server/issues/304.

Comment: Thank you :D. i just realized this right after i posted this question hahhaa thanks though :D this would be helpful to everyone.